# Inverse Kinematics locks ignored

Tags: armature, constraints, inverse-kinematics

Here is a very simple leg.

[image]

Leg.lower.L has an ik constraint applied, of chain length 2.

[image]

Foot.L has no ik applied but copies its rotation from IK_Foot.L

As discussed here [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/186647/how-to-limit-rotation-on-the-last-bone-of-an-ik-chain)  this enables the Inverse Kinematics fields of Leg.lower.L & Leg.upper.L

I want to limit the rotations of the upper leg hat may be caused by ik. To test the extreme case, suppose I attempt to prohibit rotations of Leg.upper.L completely. I have applied Lock IK for X, Y & Z.

[image]

However, as you can see, those locks are ignored.

[image]

Why are the locks having no effect?

Blender v2.83.0 on Linux

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Pole Target interferes or takes president over the Inverse Kinematics constraining in the Bone Properties tab for the last bone in the chain.

Some info [here](https://developer.blender.org/T28313) and (more or less accurate info with a bunch of links) [here](https://devtalk.blender.org/t/pole-target-and-inverse-kinematics-limits/5604)

I think that sadly there aren't any (easy) workarounds. Non that I'm aware of in any case.

Comment: That bug report & attached demo file describes my problem exactly. Seems you have to tiptoe around stuff that broken when trying to use ik.

Comment: Yes, it helps to be aware of it. : ) I guess it is an old problem rooted in certain foundations that makes it hard to deal with.